# Conda install all packages from one env in a new env

Tags: conda

Let's say we have an environment `env_og` with a set of packages `S_og` installed.

I want to create a new env `env_new` with:

1. Some specified new packages `S_new`
2. The original packages `S_og` BUT I don't care about the versions

   1. So no need to try solving the environment too seriously. *Update all you need.*

Answer (score 0):

Export, edit, and recreate.

```bash
# export env definition
conda env export -n env_og --no-builds > env_og.yaml

# edit env_og.yaml to add or remove packages/versions etc.

# create new env
conda env create -n env_new -f env_og.yaml
```

The `--no-builds` is optional - it omits the build strings from the packages, but still keeps the versions. Another potential option is the `--from-history`, which only includes explicit specifications that the user has given during the history of the environment.

Comment: I'd like to avoid long environment solving times, so `--from-history` looks interesting. Should care about versions only if I'd specified them explicitly before. Thanks! Will try soon.